# Using ngfor async pipe on ng-template

Tags: angular

I tried with async pipe on div, It works. but if i try with ng-template it fails.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of 
    portfolios$ | async; let index=i">
    <mat-form-field class="col-6">
        <mat-label>Select Client</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="clientID" 
            matInput (selectionChange)="changeClient($event.value)">
            <mat-option >
                {{ c.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="col-6">
        <mat-label>Select Portfolio</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="portfolioID" 
            matInput (selectionChange)="updateFormValuesToStore($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let c of 
                item.Portfolio">
                {{ c.portfolioName }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this in `<ng-template>`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to pass options in a dropdown thats in the form.

Comment: What I mean is, why `<ng-template>`?

Comment: `<ng-template>` is used for if-else condition in html template.

Comment: 2 dropdowns use the same json data that is nested. Can you please help on this. I am trying to make a stackbltz for clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `<ng-container>` instead, which is more appropriate.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of portfolios$ | async; let index=i">
   {{ item }}
</ng-container>
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to `<ng-template #name>` in multiple locations, you would create one `<ng-template>` and then render it in an `<ng-container>` using `*ngTemplateOutlet="name"`

In your situation, you would do something like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="portfolios"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="portfolios"></ng-container>

<ng-template #portfolios>
  <div *ngFor="let item of portfolios$ | async">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkcfds

#### How to apply this to your example

In light of your updated example, you would apply this concept like this:

```html
<mat-form-field class="col-6">
  <mat-label>Select Client</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="clientID" matInput 
      (selectionChange)="changeClient($event.value)">
    <mat-option >
      {{ c.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="col-6">
  <mat-label>Select Portfolio</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="portfolioID" matInput 
      (selectionChange)="updateFormValuesToStore($event)">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="#portfolioOptions">
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<ng-template #portfolioOptions>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of portfolios$ | async">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let c of item.Portfolio">
      {{ c.portfolioName }}
    </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Notice how I'm restricting the loop to create just the options. I've copied your loop logic as it is in your question, even though it looks a little odd to me.

Comment: I did ng-container, that works. But it gives more form-fields. But i am looking for more options in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz to demo this

Comment: You can fix this if you apply the *concept* of my answer to your updated code example

Comment: I've added an example of how you might do this to my answer

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkcfds here is the stackblitz 
that form have 2 fields(country and city). Now am trying to do with observable in template itself.

Comment: That's just my original stackblitz? Have you seen my updated example? Can you explain why that doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem since there are no dropdowns in it. 
I am looking for only 2 dropdowns and data is nested in that dropdown options. Instead.. I am getting multiple dropdowns with single option in each dropdown.

Comment: Your **general** problem is about how to query your observable once and render it in mulitple locations. I have demonstrated that. Can you not figure out how to apply it to your example? I've still not seen a stackblitz that demonstrates why this doesn't work.